# D3 force directed graph with clustering around average for integer nodes

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I've been searching online for a bit about how to do this, but have found no definitive answers so far. I was looking to create a force directed graph type thing that clusters nodes around the average value of some integer node.

Right now there is a form being used to input two values (node1 and node2). Node 1 is an integer that refers to the amount of times a character appears in a TV show and Node 2 is the name of the chracter.

Is there some way I can make a distribution of the character nodes based on the amount of times they appear in the show? Right now there is only clustering if the integer value is the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The force layout doesn't really implement any kind of clustering. The closest thing I can think of is [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841) of multiple foci. Is that what you're looking for?